# SQL Server : how to convert the value of an int to hh:mm

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an older database that stores the date and time in two different columns, which is fine in this scenario, however in the time column I have an int that seems to represent the time the entry originated.

As an example:

- `430` would be `04:30 AM`
- `9` would be `00:09 AM`
- `1350` would be `1:50 PM`

Is there a way in SQL I can convert those values to display as `04:30 AM`, etc?

Comment: "*Is there a way...?*" Probably. Show us what you've tried already, and where you're getting stuck/why your previous attempts aren't meeting your requirements. Also, you should tag the RDBMS engine you're using, as answers can vary widely between them.

Comment: I apologize, I updated as I'm using microsoft sql server.

I tried to cast as time, but got that an explicit conversion from int to time was not allowed.

Comment: You would have to convert to varchar with some `0` padding on the left and then parse that to `Time` or `DateTime`. Give it a try and see how far you get then update your question with where you are stuck.

Comment: Hey Igor, I'm able to convert to varchar, but when trying to parse that, I get the error the Parse is not a built in function.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Sorry, there was a bug in my original query: If the hour was 12PM, then it showed it as 0. This has been fixed below.

```
   SELECT CONCAT( CAST((IIF(Tim < 1300, Tim, Tim % 1200)) / 100 AS nvarchar),
       ':',
       IIF(Time_Col % 100 < 10,'0',''), -- this adds the '0' for mins less than 10
       CAST( Time_Col % 100 AS nvarchar),
       IIF(Time_Col > 1159,' PM',' AM')) 
       FROM Your_Table
```

The key here is to use integer divides and "modulo" operators to parse the time value. Note that it does *not* perform any error checking, so if the `int` value is not well formatted to begin with, you will get a wrong time string from this code. You can easily add some error checking (test for minutes greater than 59 or hours greater than 23 for example).

Answer (score 0):

I would just convert to a `time`:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(minute, (t / 100)* 60 + ( t % 100), 0))
from (values (125)) v(t)
```

You can use `format()` or `convert()` if you want to then convert this to a particular string representation.

For instance:

```
select format(dateadd(minute, (t / 100)* 60 + ( t % 100), 0), N'hh\:mm tt')
```

Comment: I'm curious how the performance of converting to `time` and then back to a string compares to my more complex string concatenation below? Obviously converting to time format is preferable if the results are to be written back to the database, but if it's just for reporting, is there more overhead? Regardless, your code does look cleaner.